# XMPPFramework install through cocoapods failing because of dependency

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods, xcode8, xmppframework

I'm using cocopods version 0.39.0
When I try to install the pod for XMPPFramework (pod 'XMPPFramework', :git => "https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework.git", :branch => 'master'), I get the following error:

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>
> libidn (~> 1.33.0) required by XMPPFramework (3.7.0)

Help?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Added the line:

> `pod 'libidn', '~> 1.33.0'`

In the podfile since it is a dependency.